# How to fix inconsistencies in Java Guessing Game

Tags: java

Here I am once again. I have listened to all the previous suggestions, but because my course hasn't taught me about methods I'm wary of using one. The program should prompt the user to enter a number and a maximum number of guesses, generate a random number, have the user exhaust all the guesses or guess the correct number, then ask whether the user wants to play again. I noticed three errors and if you could help identify their solutions I will be extremely grateful:

1. If I enter a negative number twice in the guesses does not produce anything (I’m assuming a runtime error), same goes for if I enter 0 twice in the guesses.
2. After the second round of the game it doesn’t ask the user whether they would like to play again.
3. It is inconsistent when recognizing when the maximum number of guesses is greater than the total possible amount of numbers. i.e. If I enter 1 for guess and 1 for upper limit, this shouldn’t display the message that I should “challenge” myself, because 0 and 1 are two possible numbers being generated, greater than 1, because 2 yet it still displays that.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Hello! Here are the rules for this game:");

        System.out.println("1. You choose the limit of the secret number!");

        System.out.println("2. I generate the secret number!");

        System.out.println("3. You choose the maximum number of guesses!");

        System.out
                .println("4. You try to guess the secret number I generated within the number of guesses you entered!");

        System.out.println("5. You may win a prize!");

        System.out.println(
                "With that being said, would you like to play? If yes please enter true, if not please enter false.");

        boolean wantToPlay = input.nextBoolean();

        while (wantToPlay != true) {
            System.out.println("Thank you and remember to wash your hands! You may close me.");

            System.out.println(
                    "Did you accidentally press false? If yes please enter true, if not you may leave the program. ");

            wantToPlay = input.nextBoolean();

        }

        System.out.println(
                "Please enter the limit of the secret number. Please note it must be a greater than 0 positive integer.");

        System.out.println("Please note that your secret number will be between zero and the number you just entered.");

        int upperBound = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("The upper bound you entered is" + " " + upperBound + "." + " "
                + "Is that correct? If yes please enter true, if not please enter false.");

        boolean yesOrNo = input.nextBoolean();

        if (upperBound <= 0) {
            yesOrNo = false;
        }

        while (yesOrNo != true) {
            System.out.println(
                    "Please enter the new upper bound of the secret number. Remember it must be a greater than 0 positive integer.");

            upperBound = input.nextInt();

            System.out.println("The upper bound you entered is" + " " + upperBound + "." + " "
                    + "Is that correct? If yes please enter true, if not please enter false. ");

            yesOrNo = input.nextBoolean();

            if (upperBound <= 0) {
                yesOrNo = false;
            }
        }

        int secretNumber = (int) (Math.random() * upperBound);

        System.out.println(
                "Please enter the maximum number of guesses. Please note it must be a greater than 0 positive integer.");

        int numberOfGuesses = input.nextInt();

        if (numberOfGuesses >= ++secretNumber) {
            System.out.println(
                    "Please note that the number of guesses you entered is equal or greater than the possible number of values for the secret number.");

            System.out.println("If you would like more of a challenge please re-enter the number of guesses below.");
        }

        System.out.println("The number of guesses you entered is" + " " + numberOfGuesses + "." + " "
                + "Is that correct? If yes please enter true, if not please enter false.");

        boolean yesOrNo2 = input.nextBoolean();

        if (numberOfGuesses <= 0) {
            yesOrNo2 = false;
        }

        while (yesOrNo2 != true) {
            System.out.println(
                    "Please enter the new number of guesses. Remember it must be a greater than 0 positive integer.");

            numberOfGuesses = input.nextInt();

            if (numberOfGuesses >= ++secretNumber) {
                System.out.println(
                        "Please note that the number of guesses you entered is equal or greater than the possible number of values for the secret number.");

                System.out
                        .println("If you would like more of a challenge please re-enter the number of guesses below.");

                System.out.println(
                        "If not you can still continue with your previous number as long as you re-enter it below.");

            }

            numberOfGuesses = input.nextInt();

            System.out.println("The number of guesses you entered is" + " " + numberOfGuesses + "." + " "
                    + "Is that correct? If yes please enter true, if not please enter false. ");

            yesOrNo2 = input.nextBoolean();

            if (numberOfGuesses <= 0) {
                yesOrNo2 = false;
            }

        }

        boolean loop = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfGuesses; ++i) {
            System.out.println("Please enter your guess.");

            int guesses = input.nextInt();

            if (guesses > secretNumber) {
                System.out.println("Your guess is too high.");
            }

            if (guesses < secretNumber) {
                System.out.println("Your guess is too low.");
            }

            if (guesses == secretNumber) {
                System.out.println("Your guess is correct.");

                System.out.println("Congragulations you won the game.");

                loop = true;

                break;
            }
        }

        if (loop == false) {
            System.out.println("Sorry you lost the game.");

            System.out.println(
                    "Would you like to see the secret number? If so please enter true, if not please enter false");

            boolean seeSecretNumber = input.nextBoolean();

            if (seeSecretNumber == true) {
                System.out.println("The secret number was " + secretNumber);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Would you like to play again? If so, please enter true, if not you may enter no.");

        boolean playAgain = input.nextBoolean();

        while (playAgain == true) {
            System.out.println(
                    "Please enter the limit of the secret number. Please note it must be a greater than 0 positive integer.");

            System.out.println(
                    "Please note that your secret number will be between zero and the number you just entered.");

            upperBound = input.nextInt();

            System.out.println("The upper bound you entered is" + " " + upperBound + "." + " "
                    + "Is that correct? If yes please enter true, if not please enter false.");

            yesOrNo = input.nextBoolean();

            if (upperBound <= 0) {
                yesOrNo = false;
            }

            while (yesOrNo != true) {
                System.out.println(
                        "Please enter the new upper bound of the secret number. Remember it must be a greater than 0 positive integer.");

                upperBound = input.nextInt();

                System.out.println("The upper bound you entered is" + " " + upperBound + "." + " "
                        + "Is that correct? If yes please enter true, if not please enter false. ");

                yesOrNo = input.nextBoolean();

                if (upperBound <= 0) {
                    yesOrNo = false;
                }
            }

            secretNumber = (int) (Math.random() * upperBound);

            System.out.println(
                    "Please enter the maximum number of guesses. Please note it must be a greater than 0 positive integer.");

            numberOfGuesses = input.nextInt();

            if (numberOfGuesses >= ++secretNumber) {
                System.out.println(
                        "Please note that the number of guesses you entered is equal or greater than the possible number of values for the secret number.");

                System.out
                        .println("If you would like more of a challenge please re-enter the number of guesses below.");
            }

            System.out.println("The number of guesses you entered is" + " " + numberOfGuesses + "." + " "
                    + "Is that correct? If yes please enter true, if not please enter false.");

            yesOrNo2 = input.nextBoolean();

            if (numberOfGuesses <= 0) {
                yesOrNo2 = false;
            }

            while (yesOrNo2 != true) {
                System.out.println(
                        "Please enter the new number of guesses. Remember it must be a greater than 0 positive integer.");

                numberOfGuesses = input.nextInt();

                if (numberOfGuesses >= ++secretNumber) {
                    System.out.println(
                            "Please note that the number of guesses you entered is equal or greater than the possible number of values for the secret number.");

                    System.out.println(
                            "If you would like more of a challenge please re-enter the number of guesses below.");

                    System.out.println(
                            "If not you can still continue with your previous number as long as you re-enter it below.");

                }

                numberOfGuesses = input.nextInt();

                System.out.println("The number of guesses you entered is" + " " + numberOfGuesses + "." + " "
                        + "Is that correct? If yes please enter true, if not please enter false. ");

                yesOrNo2 = input.nextBoolean();

                if (numberOfGuesses <= 0) {
                    yesOrNo2 = false;
                }

            }

            loop = false;

            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfGuesses; ++i) {
                System.out.println("Please enter your guess.");

                int guesses = input.nextInt();

                if (guesses > secretNumber) {
                    System.out.println("Your guess is too high.");
                }

                if (guesses < secretNumber) {
                    System.out.println("Your guess is too low.");
                }

                if (guesses == secretNumber) {
                    System.out.println("Your guess is correct.");

                    System.out.println("Congragulations you won the game.");

                    loop = true;

                    break;
                }
            }

            if (loop == false) {
                System.out.println("Sorry you lost the game.");

                System.out.println(
                        "Would you like to see the secret number? If so please enter true, if not please enter false");

                boolean seeSecretNumber = input.nextBoolean();

                if (seeSecretNumber == true) {
                    System.out.println("The secret number was " + secretNumber);

                    break;
                }
            }

        }

        System.out.println("Would you like to play again? If so please enter true, if not please enter false.");

        playAgain = input.nextBoolean();

        if (playAgain == false) {
            System.out.println("Thank you for playing, have a good day and wash your hands!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Methods and functions are your friend. I highly recomend you start learning about them. They will reduce the amount of code you write and make it easier to read. A quick duckduckgo.com search of "java methods" will take you to Tutorialspoint and W3Schools pages.

I recommend using (or learning) the debugger on your IDE (e.g. Netbeans, Eclipse). You will find it makes fault finding hundreds of times easier.

First rule of dealing with user input: don't allow user input.

Other general rules for dealing with user input: Users dont read instructions, users will do the opposite of your instructions, users will try and do things to your program you've never thought of, limit as much as possible all user input, validate every user input everytime.

These are the possible solutions to your errors for you.

Error 1. User input validation will solve this - there is not a requirement for negetive numbers.

Error 2. Putting the game code into a game while loop `while(continueGame)` will solve this. You start off with boolean continueGame = true. At the end of the game you ask the question "do you want to play again?" yes = true, no = false. The loop will or will not run again dependant on the answer.

Error 3. Change `if (numberOfGuesses >= ++secretNumber)` to `if(numberOfGuessess > secretNumber)`